# JSF commandbutton ajax: how to capture the success/fail event

Tags: ajax, redirect, jsf-2

my current code.

```
<h:form>
   <h:panelGroup id="messagePanel" layout="block">
       <h:messages errorStyle="color: red" infoStyle="color: green" layout="table"/>
   </h:panelGroup>
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">

        // some form input stuff here..

    </h:panelGrid>         

   <h:commandButton class="register-btn" action="#{accountController.create}" value="#{bundle.Register}">
        <f:ajax event="action" execute="@form" render="messagePanel"/>
   </h:commandButton>                       
</h:form>
```

messagePanel is where the validation errors displays.

I want to know how to capture the success event.

[done] if user input some incorrect values, it does an ajax validation and displays the incorrect values

[problem] if success it should redirect to another page.

**updated

create method

```
public String create() {
        try {

            getFacadeUser().create(currentUser);

            JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage(ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("AccountCreated"));
            return prepareCreate();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(e, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
            return null;
        }
    }

public String prepareCreate() {
    current = new Account();
    selectedItemIndex = -1;
    return "index";
}
```

i'm using JSF 2.1

Comment: Show us you `create` method code, and please post version of JSF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not correct way to do redirection with AJAX request. You should use [ExternalContext.redirect()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#redirect%28java.lang.String%29) instead:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("yourUrl");
```

In that way you will receive partial response from server to, which will do redirection:

```
<partial-response>
  <redirect url="yourUrl">
  </redirect>
</partial-response>
```

String which you returned in this method is irrelevant, you can even return `null`.

Comment: ah thanks! it works, if i may add another question, how about if i want to invoke a javascript after a successful creation? currently my create form is a pop up modal, what i want is to just hide the modal after a successful creation, will this be possible? thanks!

Comment: You should post separated question. Don't practice two post additional questions in comments.